# Getting the active element within ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Im trying to get the component that is active/focused at a given time. I already know that you can get a HTMLElement with the cross-browser javascript function `document.activeElement`.

How can I cast this element to a Ext.Component or does ExtJs have a similar function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @sra for this solution:

```
let activeComponent = Ext.get(Ext.Element.getActiveElement());
```

Comment: Note IE may sometimes throw a Unspecified Error so you should wrap it into a try/catch block. And if it stays undefined use the `document.body`

Comment: Also note that there is a static helper method that wraps this for you http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-getActiveElement

Comment: Thank you for your replies, how do you use `getActiveElement()`?

Comment: Use it like a static method `Ext.Element.getActiveElement()`

Comment: Do you know how to allow components or containers to get focused?

Comment: You should ask a new question with your specific problem :) There is more likely to get an answer instead of asking it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this : [Ext.FocusManager](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.FocusManager). I have never used this feature, could you tell me if it fits with your needs?

Comment: I know this focusmanager and it doesnt have what I was looking for. I use focusmanager to debug some visual aspects of my application.